# How to execute the command (a string) in a subshell apart from the os.system() and subprocess call?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying the source the Gromacs executables with the os.system method, but unfortunately, the source of executables is not happening. I can define the source in .bashrc but I have to keep changing the sources with different versions of Gromacs.

`os.system("source /usr/local/gromacs/groamcs2019.4/bin/GMXRC")`

The what I am getting is source not found, but the source location is right.

Comment: Can you post your actual traceback?

Comment: sorry i didn't get you ??

Comment: Add the full error into the post

Comment: You're using `os.system("source /usr/local/gromacs/groamcs2019.4/bin/GMXRC")` isn't a mispelling in the 4th folder? I guess the right path is `os.system("source /usr/local/gromacs/gromacs2019.4/bin/GMXRC")`

Comment: Nope it's right

Comment: @JammyDodger the traceback says only (sh: 1: source: not found), the only problem is the whatever I am defining in the source is not accepting